# Tracking player's movement in WPF C# using Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm trying to build a project of the original pacman game in WPF C# using Canvas and I got stuck on the ghosts tracking and movement.
the Idea is to check if the ghost will move through a wall the next move and prevent it.

But apparently I programed it wrong and the ghost is moving until it reaches the wall, then moving a step backwards, and then again move to the wall and so on.

How am I supposed to fix the algorithm? and of course, If you have any other idea I'd love to hear it.

Thanks!

Here's is the ghosts movement relevant code:

```
//flags are used to check if the ghosts next move is through a wall
        double x1 = Canvas.GetTop(pacman);
        double y = Canvas.GetLeft(pacman);
        if (Math.Abs(Canvas.GetTop(redGuy) - x1) > Math.Abs(Canvas.GetLeft(redGuy) - y) && (flagUp == false || flagDown == false))
        {
            if (Canvas.GetTop(redGuy) < x1)
            {
                if (flagDown == false)
                {
                    Canvas.SetTop(redGuy, Canvas.GetTop(redGuy) + ghostSpeed);
                }
                else if (flagRight == false || flagLeft == false)
                {
                    if (Canvas.GetLeft(redGuy) < y && flagLeft == false)
                    {
                        Canvas.SetLeft(redGuy, Canvas.GetLeft(redGuy) + ghostSpeed);
                    }
                    else if (flagRight == false)
                    {
                        Canvas.SetLeft(redGuy, Canvas.GetLeft(redGuy) - ghostSpeed);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (flagUp == false)
                {
                    Canvas.SetTop(redGuy, Canvas.GetTop(redGuy) - ghostSpeed);
                }
                else if (flagRight == false || flagLeft == false)
                {
                    if (Canvas.GetLeft(redGuy) < y && flagLeft == false)
                    {
                        Canvas.SetLeft(redGuy, Canvas.GetLeft(redGuy) + ghostSpeed);
                    }
                    else if (flagRight == false)
                    {
                        Canvas.SetLeft(redGuy, Canvas.GetLeft(redGuy) - ghostSpeed);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (flagRight == false || flagLeft == false)
        {
            if (Canvas.GetLeft(redGuy) < y)
            {
                if (flagLeft == false)
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(redGuy, Canvas.GetLeft(redGuy) + ghostSpeed);
                }
                else if (flagUp == false || flagDown == false)
                {
                    if (Canvas.GetTop(redGuy) > x1 && flagUp == false)
                    {
                        Canvas.SetTop(redGuy, Canvas.GetTop(redGuy) - ghostSpeed);
                    }
                    else if (flagDown == false)
                    {
                        Canvas.SetTop(redGuy, Canvas.GetTop(redGuy) + ghostSpeed);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (flagRight == false)
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(redGuy, Canvas.GetLeft(redGuy) - ghostSpeed);
                }
                else if (flagUp == false || flagDown == false)
                {
                    if (Canvas.GetTop(redGuy) > x1 && flagDown == false)
                    {
                        Canvas.SetTop(redGuy, Canvas.GetTop(redGuy) - ghostSpeed);
                    }
                    else if (flagRight == false)
                    {
                        Canvas.SetTop(redGuy, Canvas.GetTop(redGuy) + ghostSpeed);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say your main problem here is in game design.

Don't use UI as a data store.

Instead use UI as a representation of your data.

I'm not sure this is really an answer suitable for SO but it's not going to fit in comments.

Think of your playing area as being a grid of squares. Roughly the size of your pacman/player.

Represent this internally with a 2d array so roughly say Square[100,80].

A given pacman or ghost has a Square they're associated with using integer x,y co-ordinates.

If a ghost has the same co-ordinates as the player then they got him.

You could still position sprites round on the canvas and calculate where they are from their co-ordinates. Alternatively the board could be represented using an itemscontrol with a canvas as itemspanel.  This is a fairly common approach you should be able to find if you search.  But basically you bind an observablecollection to itemssource of the itemscontrol. That collection has a viewmodel typed to indicate what it is.  A playerviewmodel, ghostviewmodel, wallviewmodel etc.  These are then templated into UI using datatype to match viewmodel to datatemplate.
You can position on that grid by exposing x,y properties and binding them to the canvas.left and canvas.top properties of the item container. Use a converter to calculate px values from square values.

If x and y were px values:

```
  <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=XPos}" />
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=YPos}" />
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But a square will be bigger than a px so you want some multiplication conversion via a converter.

You might think this templating business would be inefficient. It scales very well though.  For our map editing app one of the things you can do is "draw" the outline of a woods. That is translated into an area on screen in this way.  It is then filled with trees. There can be thousands of trees.

For each of these there's a treevm and a datatemplate that uses one of 3 templates.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZJVD.png

Once you have a grid you can use a pathing algorithm such as spatial A* if ghosts move towards the pacman. I can't rememember whether they do that or just move randomly.

If you're interested in designing games then many require pathing and spatial A* is probably the most commonly used. Especially if all squares are the same cost.  Our game uses spatial A* with variable cost though.

Amit's pages are good:

[http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/](http://theory.stanford.edu/%7Eamitp/GameProgramming/)

Comment: first off thank you for your comment, I do in fact wanted to try a different approach and try to implement it in a different way. If you do have an idea that follows my direction I'd like that very much. be sure that I will check out your implementation way.