# How do I check if all the children of a grid meet a certain requirement?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a battleship game in WPF C# where I hit on an enemy grid and if the opacity is an arbitrary value that signifies a ship placed there it will hit that board square. I have a function but it says displays the message that I win right on the first time that I hit a ship. I need for it to check if the whole board meets the requirement. This is the function

```
   private void checkOurWin()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < gridEnemy.Children.Count; i++)
            {
                if (((Button)gridEnemy.Children[i]).Background == Brushes.Red && ((Button)gridEnemy.Children[i]).Opacity == 1.00001)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You have won congratulations!");
                }
            }
        }
```

I am looping over all the children of the grid here and checking if the background has been already uncovered with a certain opacity but how do I do it for the entire grid and not just one item? Thanks!

Comment: Be careful with `==` and `float` ...

Comment: Slowly losing the will to type the same  thing repeatedly.
You should use an itemscontrol and template out data into your UI. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75054560/tracking-players-movement-in-wpf-c-sharp-using-canvas

Answer (score 2):

You may use LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;
...

private void CheckOurWin()
{
    if (gridEnemy.Children
        .OfType<Button>()
        .All(b => b.Background == Brushes.Red && b.Opacity > 1d))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have won congratulations!");
    }
}
```

As a note, you should not be using UI element properties to store additional state data, like setting Opacity greater than 1.0. Use additional data fields in the MainWindow class (or even better, a view model class) or at least use the Buttons' `Tag` property.

Also note that a floating point comparison like `Opacity == 1.00001` is inherently unsafe due to the way floating point values are stored. Such comparisons should generally be avoided.

Comment: Considering we are dealing with a game, I'd even argue there should be a game engine or something and the UI should only be there to display current state of that engine (and provide input facilities).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I undestand the code and it looks it is supposed to work but when I input it there is no change to what the program executes. Do I need a for loop counter surrounding the if statement?

Comment: No, you don't. Maybe the Buttons' Backgrounds are not Red or their Opacity is not greater than 1.

Comment: Is it possible that it is not picking up the 1.00001 opacity as greater than a 1?

Comment: I just tried changing the opacity to a 2 and still does not change what the program executes